# How to do a Magento Manual Restore?

Tags: magento, templates, themes, restore

I backed up the entire public_html folder, and had the mysql backed up as well.  I'm new to Magento so I did a clean install and a mysqlimport with the database.  Seems like the site is almost fully back in order but the template doesn't look the same.  It's using the default Magento template.  I didn't copy the entire public_html folder over for the reason of having a different mysql username/password.

I tried to copy over media, skin/frontend, and app/design/frontend folders.  I just need to get the original template back and I think the site should be fine.

Comment: are the template/design to use correctly set in admin > system > config > (catalog) design > Package/Design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento is pretty portable, it just boils down to a bunch of files and a database.  When moving/cloning an install all you need to do is move/backup the entire fileset and the database (as you have already done) and when restoring put the fileset in the new location and import the sql dump into new database.

When things are in place, open the file `app/etc/local.xml` and alter the database connection info for the new database.  You also need to alter the `base_url` entries in the database if the domain has changed, so open the `core_config_data` table in the new database and find the entries with a `path` column content like `%base_url`:

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE '%base_url';
```

Alter the domain entries returned by this query accordingly.

Finally bear in mind there can be a large number of files in the `var/cache/` and `var/session/` directories which will increase the size of the backup.  It is safe to delete the contents of `var/cache/` but deleting the contents of `var/session/` will kill all user sessions, so *definitely* thing twice before doing this.

I would suggest you follow this procedure in restoring your Magento install.

Comment: I did all of this and for some reason the website doesn't look the same at all.  The theme is completely different.

Comment: If your store is not an identical clone after moving it to the new location by following the instructions above then something else must have been changed.

Comment: Magento is certainly not "pretty portable", in fact it's pretty unportable because extensions are tied to both database and code heavily. The database is not just data, it's controlling functionality of the store.

Comment: Not really clear on your meaning here, but I'm making the point that its easy to move a Magento install to another location/server etc just by moving both the fileset and associated database.  I'm not trying to suggest you can separate the fileset and associated database and still have things work for instance with some other database, clearly that will fail.